# Como agregar información del payer usando checkout básico

Tags: android, mercadopago

Estoy implementando checkout básico en mi app, utilizando el metodo startCheckoutActivity, de esta forma:

```
new MercadoPago.StartActivityBuilder()
                .setActivity(this)
                .setPublicKey(BuildConfig.MP_PUBLIC_KEY)
                .setCheckoutPreferenceId(BuildConfig.MP_PREF_ID)
                .setDecorationPreference(decorationPreference)
                .startCheckoutActivity();
```

Al momento de probar la funcionalidad me muestra un mensaje que indica que es necesario un email, pero no encuentro la forma de set la info del payer (para colocar el email).

Answer (score -1):

El email es un parametro que debes enviar durante la creación de la preferencia, es decir en el snippet de codigo que usas en el backend para generar el preference_id.

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/receive-payments/additional-info/

Comment: Que pasa si la preferencia ya habia sido creada con ciertos parámetros? Debo crear la preferencia cada vez que vaya a usarla si tendrá un correo diferente cada vez?

Comment: Si, una preferencia representa un conjunto de características que describen un requerimiento de pago, esto incluye la identidad del pagador